# Unique constraint is conflict select and update in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, unique-constraint

We have a Unique key on a Document Image upload table. While update a path of Doc's image, its violating the Unique. But `select` statement returns zero for same values.

Queries:

```
select * from uploadeddocmaster 
where EmployeeCode='VSSPL-0402' and VendorCode='VEND-0001' -- 3 rows 

select * from uploadeddocmaster 
where EmployeeCode='VSSPL-0402' and VendorCode='VEND-0001' and Documentname='blurred-bg-f4mmedia-2.jpg' -- 0 row

Update uploadeddocmaster set Documentname='blurred-bg-f4mmedia-2.jpg',
ImagePath='http://ip addrs/testingimages/VSSPL-04034049489910055332026.jpg',
ModifiedBy='TNPL-0003',ActiveYn='Yes',DeleteYn='No'
where EmployeeCode='VSSPL-0402' and VendorCode='VEND-0001' -- constraint vialotion
```

Result set of Selects:

[image: edit 1:]

OP window of above queries and image of [image: error]:

> (3 row(s) affected)
>
> (0 row(s) affected)
>
> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 26 Violation of UNIQUE KEY
>   constraint 'UK_UploadedDocMaster_Code_Name_Side_Vendor'. Cannot insert
>   duplicate key in object 'dbo.UploadedDocMaster'. The duplicate key
>   value is (VSSPL-0402, blurred-bg-f4mmedia-2.jpg, , VEND-0001).
>   The statement has been terminated.
>
> ---

Question is, there are no records found for the where clause of update. Then why unique constraint is violated. Here my table structure.

`Alt + F1` of table and Column table:

```
Column_name     Type    Computed    Length  Prec    Scale   Nullable    TrimTrailingBlanks  FixedLenNullInSource    Collation
SearialNo       int         no      4       10      0       no          (n/a)               (n/a)                   NULL
EmployeeCode    varchar     no      15                      no          no                  no                      SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
DocumentName    varchar     no      100                     no          no                  no                      SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
Side            varchar     no      10                      yes         no                  yes                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
ImagePath       varchar     no      -1                      no          no                  no                      SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
VendorCode      varchar     no      15                      no          no                  no                      SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
ActiveYn        varchar     no      3                       yes         no                  yes                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
DeleteYn        varchar     no      3                       yes         no                  yes                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
CreatedDate     datetime    no      8                       yes         (n/a)               (n/a)                   NULL
CreatedBy       varchar     no      15                      no          no                  no                      SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
ModifiedDate    datetime    no      8                       yes         (n/a)               (n/a)                   NULL
ModifiedBy      varchar     no      15                      no          no                  no                      SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

`Alt + F1` of table and Index table:

```
index_name                                  index_description                                       index_keys
UK_UploadedDocMaster_Code_Name_Side_Vendor  nonclustered, unique, unique key located on PRIMARY     EmployeeCode, DocumentName, Side, VendorCode
```

`Alt + F1` of table and Constraint table:

```
constraint_type         constraint_name                             delete_action   update_action   status_enabled  status_for_replication  constraint_keys
UNIQUE (non-clustered)  UK_UploadedDocMaster_Code_Name_Side_Vendor  (n/a)           (n/a)           (n/a)           (n/a)                   EmployeeCode, DocumentName, Side, VendorCode
```

Thanks,

Pugal.

Comment: You have *3* rows that you're going to try to change to have the *same* value and you're wondering how that violates uniqueness?

Comment: Just to expand on Damien's comment, your first query returns 3 rows. That's the same `WHERE` clause you're using for your `UPDATE`. The duplicated rows aren't in your table, they're in your query.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I mean *same values* are condition values not updated (DocumentName column) value. `where` clause values of `select` and `update` are same. Where select returns zero rows beside `update` query violates the unique constraint. And let me add select results

Comment: @EricBrandt, Let me add select results

Comment: Yes, so you're showing us 3 rows, with Serial No's 50, 51 and 52. Your `UPDATE` statements `WHERE` clause will pick out all 3 of those rows and change all of them to have a `Documentname` of `blurred-bg-f4mmedia-2.jpg` and leave the `EmployeeCode`, `Side` and `VendorCode` alone. You would then have 3 rows which are identical in those 4 columns and that's what your UNIQUE constraint prevents.

Comment: And despite what it says in the title of your question, you aren't updating the document _path_, which is _not_ a part of your unique key. You're updating the document _name_, which _is_ a part of your unique key, and you're trying to do it on three rows. That would be a key violation. Try running your `select` query again, but just use the fields in the unique key. Maybe you'll be able to see the issue then. No need to post the results. We're just trying to help you see why your update isn't going to work.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, As per Your commands, Update affects three rows. Yes. Now I understood. I did not think this way.

Comment: @EricBrandt, Hmm, error confusing me. Now I am clear. Thanks.